# How do I modify the architecture of a third-party static library? No source code

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Recently, I would like to put the written project files on cocoapods for others to use, my project file contains a third party static library, libEZOpenSDK.a, pod lib lint operation in the wrong, because this Library does not support simulator architecture.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EZDeviceInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Camera_TZYOPHomePageViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EZOpenSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Camera_TZYHistoryRecordViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in Camera_TZYOPFunctionsSDK.o
      objc-class-ref in Camera_TZYOPHomePageViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in Camera_TZYSettingViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/yuancong/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fmvnjejbnyymigeawgsdeaxjbfki/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Cameara_TZYEZFunctions.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Cameara_TZYEZFunctions normal x86_64
    Ld /Users/yuancong/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-fmvnjejbnyymigeawgsdeaxjbfki/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Cameara_TZYEZFunctions.build/Objects-normal/i386/Cameara_TZYEZFunctions normal i386
(2 failures)
```

Podspec need to set something? Or is there any way to modify the architecture of this library?

**Note: I do not have the source code for this library.**

It is best to have any way to modify the library support simulator architecture, thank you.

View information about the library via lipo -info:

```
yuancongdeiMac:~ yuancong$ lipo -info /Users/yuancong/Desktop/iOS_v4.4.0.build20170320/SDK/libEZOpenSDK.a 
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/yuancong/Desktop/iOS_v4.4.0.build20170320/SDK/libEZOpenSDK.a are: armv7 arm64 
yuancongdeiMac:~ yuancong$
```

The following is my podspec file configuration:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Cameara_TZYEZFunctions'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'Cameara_TZYEZFunctions.'


  s.description      = <<-DESC
                        Cameara_TZYEZFunctions podspec.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/tencheer2017/Cameara_TZYEZFunctions'

  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'tencheer2017' => 'stevenzhu@tencheer.com.cn' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/tencheer2017/Cameara_TZYEZFunctions.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }


  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source_files = 'Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/Classes/**/*','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/sdk/openssl/include/openssl/*.h','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/sdk/SDK/include/TestLib/*.h'
  
  s.resources = ['Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/Camera_TZYResources/images/**/*.png','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/Camera_TZYResources/xib/*.xib','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/Camera_TZYResources/storyboard/*.storyboard','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/Camera_TZYResources/other/**/*.strings']

  s.public_header_files = 'Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/Classes/**/*.h','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/sdk/openssl/include/openssl/*.h','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/sdk/SDK/include/TestLib/*.h'
  s.frameworks = 'CoreMedia', 'AudioToolbox','VideoToolbox','GLKit','OpenAL','MobileCoreServices','SystemConfiguration','CoreTelephony','AVFoundation'
  s.libraries = 'stdc++.6.0.9', 'c++','iconv.2.4.0'
  s.vendored_libraries = 'Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/sdk/SDK/libEZOpenSDK.a','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/sdk/openssl/lib/libssl.a','Cameara_TZYEZFunctions/sdk/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a'
  s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
  s.dependency 'Toast'
  s.dependency 'ZASwitch'
end
```